# How to Calibrate Touch Screen

Tags: release-hera, touchscreen

How can I calibrate a USB touch screen device? I have tried the app in the app store but it does not run. The touchscreen is 3m usb touchscreen - ex II and I am using the latest version of ElementaryOS

Answer (score 0):

Xinput and (maybe) xinput-gui may help you. I used xinput_calibrator and it worked fine.
In ubuntuforum you'll find this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/51445/how-do-i-calibrate-a-touchscreen-on-a-dual-monitor-system

Comment: I have tried running xinput_calibrator but it doesnt seem to do anything?